# Share_plus with url without using path_provider in flutter web

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies, flutter-web

I have this piece of code here that shows the image on a page with a button that could share this image to Facebook or any other social media site via url, right now most of the tutorials are asking me to use path_provider to store the bytes inside the local storage. However, i'm doing flutter web and the path_provider package does not support web, is there any alternatives to path_provider?

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:share_plus/share_plus.dart';
import 'dart:html';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;

class ImageViewer extends StatefulWidget {

  @override
  State<ImageViewer> createState() => _ImageViewerState();
}

class _ImageViewerState extends State<ImageViewer> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text("Image title"),
      ),
      body: Column(
        children: [
          AspectRatio(aspectRatio: 4/3,
          child: Image.network('https://picsum.photos/seed/548/600')),
          Row(
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            children: [
              IconButton(icon: const Icon(Icons.arrow_upward),
                tooltip: 'Upvote image',
                onPressed: () {

                },),
              IconButton(icon: const Icon(Icons.arrow_downward),
                tooltip: 'Downvote image',
                onPressed: () {
                },
              ),
              IconButton(icon: const Icon(Icons.facebook),
                tooltip: 'Downvote image',
                onPressed: () async {
                const urlImage = 'https://picsum.photos/seed/548/600';
                final url = Uri.parse(urlImage);
                final response = await http.get(url);
                final bytes = response.bodyBytes;

                // final temp = await ;
                },
              )
            ],
          ),
          const Padding(
            padding: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
            child: Text('Title'),
          ),
          const Padding(
            padding: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
            child: Text('Upvotes'),
          ),
          const Padding(
            padding: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
            child: Text('Description'),
          ),
          
        ],

      ),
    );
  }
}
```